# TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

Tags: scipy, typeerror, sympy, numerical-integration

The code which I wrote might look foolish, because it is integration of a derivative function. since it is the basic foundation to the other code which I'm writing on acoustical analysis. this analysis contains integration of different derivative functions which are in multiplication. for this purpose I'm using SciPy for integration and sympy for differentiation. but it is giving an error showing TypeError("can't convert expression to float"). below is the code which I wrote. hoping a solution for this.

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
var('r')
def diff(r):
    r=symbols('x')
    Z = 64.25 * r ** 5 - 175.71 *r ** 4 + 170.6 *r ** 3 - 71.103 *r ** 2 + 3 * r
    E=sympy.diff(Z,r)
    print(E)
    return E
R=quad(diff,0,1)[0]
print(R)
```

Comment: quad is a numeric integrator.   sympy expression (and symbols) won't work.  Use a sympy integrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I'm a bit confused by your statement "integration of a derivative function" since the fundamental theorem of calculus would suggest that this is just a waste of CPU cycles. I'll presume that you know what you're doing though and that you just want to be able to compute some definite integrals numerically...

The SymPy expression that you want to integrate is this:

```
In [33]: from sympy import *

In [34]: r = symbols("x")  # Why are you calling this x?

In [35]: Z = 64.25 * r ** 5 - 175.71 * r ** 4 + 170.6 * r ** 3 - 71.103 * r ** 2 +
    ...: 3 * r

In [36]: E = diff(Z, r)

In [37]: E
Out[37]: 
        4           3          2                
321.25⋅x  - 702.84⋅x  + 511.8⋅x  - 142.206⋅x + 3
```

There are a two basic ways to do this with SymPy:

```
In [38]: integrate(E, (r, 0, 1))  # symbolic integration
Out[38]: -8.96299999999999

In [39]: Integral(E, (r, 0, 1)).evalf()  # numeric integration
Out[39]: -8.96300000000002
```

Note that had you used exact rational numbers you would see a more accurate result in either case:

```
In [40]: nsimplify(E)
Out[40]: 
      4          3         2              
1285⋅x    17571⋅x    2559⋅x    71103⋅x    
─────── - ──────── + ─────── - ─────── + 3
   4         25         5        500      

In [41]: integrate(nsimplify(E), (r, 0, 1))
Out[41]: 
-8963 
──────
 1000 

In [42]: Integral(nsimplify(E), (r, 0, 1)).evalf()
Out[42]: -8.96300000000000
```

While the approaches above are very accurate and work nicely for this particular integral which is easy to compute both symbolically and numerically they are both slower than using something like scipy's quad function which works with machine precision floating point and efficient numpy arrays for the calculation. To use scipy's quad function you need to lambdify your expression into an ordinary Python function:

```
In [44]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [45]: f = lambdify(r, E, "numpy")

In [46]: f(0)
Out[46]: 3.0

In [47]: f(1)
Out[47]: -8.99600000000001

In [48]: quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
Out[48]: -8.963000000000001
```

What `lambdify` does is just to generate an efficient Python function for you. You can see the code that it uses like this:

```
In [51]: import inspect

In [52]: print(inspect.getsource(f))
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return 321.25*x**4 - 702.84*x**3 + 511.8*x**2 - 142.206*x + 3
```

The `quad` routine will pass in numpy arrays for x and so this can be very efficient. If you have high-order polynomials then sympy's `horner` function can be used to optimise the expression:

```
In [53]: horner(E)
Out[53]: x⋅(x⋅(x⋅(321.25⋅x - 702.84) + 511.8) - 142.206) + 3.0

In [54]: f2 = lambdify(r, horner(E), "numpy")

In [56]: print(inspect.getsource(f2))
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return x*(x*(x*(321.25*x - 702.84) + 511.8) - 142.206) + 3.0
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#integrals
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyfuncs.horner

Comment: `quad` integrates a scalar function of one scalar variable.  There are `scipy` functions that allow you to set a "vectorize" switch, indicating that your function can be evaluated at many points at once, but `quad` isn't one of those.  It's smarts and relative efficiency come from the Fortran QUADPACK.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Benjamin . Lambdify helped me in completing the final code.